# Best way to generate a human face over a face generated by FaceFormer framework?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-networks, opencv, deep-face

[FaceFormer](https://evelynfan.github.io/audio2face/) framework generates a talking face from audio, focusing on the lip and face movement when a person talks. Now from that what would be the best way to generate a human face on top of that?
I tried [DeepFaceLive](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLive) that didn't give good results as that swaps face only.
The first image is given by my FaceFormer (is was a video actually ) and when you use DeepFaceLive (deep fake) to replace it looks like a genie in the bottle.
What would your suggestion be around it ??
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "a face generated by FaceFormer framework," as I am not familiar with this specific framework. However, here are some general approaches that you could use to generate a human face:

Use a 3D modeling software: There are many 3D modeling software programs that allow you to create a human face by manipulating geometric shapes and surfaces. These programs often have tools that allow you to adjust the shape of the face, add facial features like eyes and a nose, and apply textures and materials to create a realistic appearance.

Use a face generation tool: There are several tools and frameworks available that allow you to generate a human face using machine learning algorithms. These tools often require you to input a set of parameters or characteristics, such as the shape of the face, the color of the eyes, and the style of the hair, and the tool will generate a face based on those characteristics.

Use a database of pre-generated faces: Another option is to use a database of pre-generated human faces and select one that closely matches the face you want to create. These databases can often be found online and may include a variety of different facial features and styles.

I hope these suggestions are helpful! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hello there
Thanks for the reply. Can you please give me an example of the face-generation tools and databases you're talking about? For I cannot find much which is relevant to me :(